# Two Foreach loop compare solution

Tags: php, instagram

I have two arrays:

first:

```
"data":  [
     {
      "username": "ishaza_",
      "bio": "All photos by me:$",
      "website": "",
      "full_name": "Shaza",
      "id": "411073318"
    },
     {
      "username": "taylovesrissa",
      "bio": "",
      "website": "",

      "full_name": "Taylor Angell",
      "id": "750547868"
    },
     {
      "username": "a_sh997",
      "bio": "",
      "website": "",

      "full_name": "Ahmed",
      "id": "679088716"
    }
]
```

second :

```
"data":  [
     {
      "username": "ishaza_",
      "bio": "All photos by me:$",
      "website": "",

      "full_name": "Shaza",
      "id": "411073318"
    },
     {
      "username": "taylovesrissa",
      "bio": "",
      "website": "",

      "full_name": "Taylor Angell",
      "id": "750547868"
    },
     {
      "username": "a_sh997",
      "bio": "",
      "website": "",

      "full_name": "Ahmed",
      "id": "6790887163"
    }
]
```

i want to print those data which are not present in the first and second both.

i have used a foreach loop but it is giving abnormal result like every item is being printed multiple times.

my code is:

```
foreach ($UserFollows->data as $entry1) {

    foreach ($UserFollower->data as $entry2) {

        $e1=$entry1->id;
        $e2=$entry2->id;
        if($e1!=$e2) {
            print''.$e1.'</br>';
        }
    }   
}
```

here `$UserFollows` and `$UserFollower` represents two arrays .this array comes from instagram API.actually I want to compare two api of instagram one is follows and other followed-by and want to print those data which are not listed in both api result .

but i cant understand why my code returns abnormal result with foreach loop

Comment: You're looping round the $UserFollower array for every record in the $UserFollows array - I don't think that's right?

Comment: perhaps you want array_diff? Moreover what is your definition for "abnormal"?

Comment: what is the right way @Stanyer

Comment: abnormal means my in my result every item print for multiple time @artragis

Answer (score 5):

Use **[array_uintersect](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-uintersect.php)** to compute the intersection of arrays, compares data by a callback function.

```
$result = array_uintersect($UserFollows->data, $UserFollower->data, function($a, $b) {
  return strcmp($a->id, $b->id);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to find differences, but your code does not do that (it prints every `$entry1` n times, with n the number of items in `$UserFollower->data` minus the number of items in `$UserFollower->data` that match the given item.

Try something like this:

```
foreach ($UserFollows->data as $entry1) {
    if !(contains($UserFollower->data,$entry1)) {
        print '' . $entry1->id . '</br>';
    }
}

function contains($arr, $entry) {
    $e1=$entry1->id;
    foreach ($arr as $entry2) {
        $e2=$entry2->id;
        if ($e1 == $e2)
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: yeah, using a builtin function is most likely better (at least performance-wise that's what I'd expect), but I hope this post will also help to understand why his version didn't work ;)

Comment: True enough for his understanding, but it is also more readable using builtin.